# Connecting to a remote MySQL database on a local PC using another PC

Tags: mysql, client-server, mysql-workbench

I want to develop a project for some college work. For this project i want to create a database in MySQL and I should be able to access this database from 2 different PC's which have MySQL workbench installed on it. I can use one of the PC's as the server or even a third PC as the server for the MySQL database. Someone please help me in doing this as i am unable to find any solutions online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much of an issue here.

1. Download and install the server from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html).
2. Then install it on a computer within the same LAN of other computers
   that will query the database.
3. Get the local ip of the computer on which the server is up and
   running (on windows run cmd and then `ipconfig`) then look for
   `IPv4 Address` value of the LAN.
4. Then establish the connection from other computers using that ip
   value as host value configuration.